# Convert perl hash with multiple values into python dict

Tags: python, perl, dictionary, data-structures, hash

I have a perl file named ips.pl at `C:\Perl\test\ips.pl` which contains 6 perl hashes. Each hash contains 1 key and 2 values.
The file contains below data.

```
{
 '192.168.111.1' => [
            '192.168.111.2',
            '192.168.111.3',
 ],

 '192.168.111.4'  =>  [
                    '192.168.111.5',
                    '192.168.111.6',
 ],

 '192.168.111.7' => [
                     '192.168.111.8',
                     '192.168.111.9',
 ],
}
```

How Can I convert this perl file to python readable? I need result in 3 separate Python Dict. The required result should be like

```
dict1 = {'192.168.111.1': '192.168.111.2'}
dict2 = {'192.168.111.1': '192.168.111.3'}
dict3 = {'192.168.111.4': '192.168.111.5'}
dict4 = {'192.168.111.4': '192.168.111.6'}
dict5 = {'192.168.111.7': '192.168.111.8'}
dict6 = {'192.168.111.7': '192.168.111.9'}
```

As am new to both perl and python, please suggest me any module which will be a easy solution for me. In case we dont have any such module then please suggest me the steps. Thanks in advance

I tried with below code,

```
import re
class PerlLikeDict( dict ):
pattern_type= type(re.compile(""))
def getitem(self, key):
    F = open("resources.pl", "r+")
    print "value of F object is", F
    print "type of object is ", type(F)
    rd=str(F.read())
    print "value of string variable rd is", rd
    #print "value of 1st is", rd[1]
    #print dict_rd == dict(rd)
    if key in self:
        return super( PerlLikeDict, self ).__getitem__( key )
    for k in self:
        if type(k) == self.pattern_type:
            if k.match(key):
                return self[k]
    raise KeyError( "key %r not found" % ( key, ) )

F = open("resources.pl", "r+")
rd=str(F.read())
print "able to read the file", rd
x=PerlLikeDict(rd)
print x
```

This is giving error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sanjaya.sahoo\workspace\my python 
learning\src\workon_local_perlfile.py", line 23, in <module>
x=PerlLikeDict(rd)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Convert it to a format that you can read and write in both worlds, like JSON. Also, if there are only three of them, then you are already done, as you've done it by hand in your question. :D

Comment: Are you sure? You can't have a python `dict` with non-unique keys.